# Prove that the roots are equal

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose that all roots of the polynomial equation
$x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2 +bx + 1 = 0$ are positive real numbers. Show that all roots of the polynomial are equal.

I am not getting any idea as to how to solve it.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose the roots are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$. Then we have $\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta}{4}=\alpha\beta\gamma\delta=1$. But the arithmetic and geometric means of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ can only be equal if $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta$.

Comment: That was fast +1!

Comment: thank you very much...stupid of me for not thinking like that....thnx again..

Comment: Too fast - $\frac{{\alpha  + \beta  + \gamma  + \delta  = 4}}{4}$?? ...THAT'S BETTER!

Comment: @Benedict Many thanks, fixed!